# First call working but subsequent call fails, using on()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a modal that allows a user to post a question to my site. The posting of the question is done via a button that calls the below function - this submits the question to the database but if the input field is blank it sends an error. In both cases, the modal is reloaded and if an error is set, it is displayed on the modal. The issue is this.....I need to repost using the reloaded modal, but jQuery is not loaded does not appear to be available after the ajax call. I originally had

```
  $("#submit_question").click(function(){.....
```

But following the jQuery documentation found that I needed either .live(), .delegate(). or .on(). Reviews on stack suggested that on(). was the one to use at this stage hence the code below. This works for the first ajax call but won't allow further calls. I have looked all over for a solution to this....and there are similar posts but my reading of them suggests that the below code is correct (but it can't be). Could someone suggest the problem?

```
$("#submit_question").on("click", function(){
     var subject = $('#question_subject');
     $.ajax({
      url: '../ajax/submit_question.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
          'subject': $('#question_subject').val(),
          'details': $('#question_details').val(),
          },
            success: function(html) {
                if(!$.trim(subject.val()).length){
                  var error = "There was an error";
                 } 
                  $('.reveal-modal').load('question_box.php', {error: error});               
                  }
               });
       return false;
     });
```

Comment: `.on` for delegation = `$(Static Parent selector).on(Event, Target Selector, Function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the selector parameter, otherwise the event is directly bound instead of delegated, which only works if the element already exists (so it doesn't work for dynamically loaded content).

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Change your code to

$(document.body).on('click', '#submit_question' ,function(){

Answer (score 1):

Try this works for you:

```
$(document).on("click","#submit_question", function(){

//Do something here..

});
```

OR

```
$(document).bind("click","#submit_question", function(){

//Do something here..

});
```